# At which line in this code is it likely to find an exception/error?

Tags: c++, error-handling, exception

This is the code:

```
template <typename T> class Ntuplet
{
    public:
        Ntuplet(std::initializer_list<T> s);
        ~Ntuplet(void);
        Ntuplet<T>& operator=(const Ntuplet<T>& t);
    private:
        size_t m_size;
        T* m_objects;

};

template<typename T>
    Ntuplet<T>& Ntuplet<T>::operator=(const Ntuplet<T>& t)
{
    if (&t == this)
        return *this;

    delete [] m_objects;
    m_size = t.m_size;
    m_objects = new T[t.m_size];
    for(int i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
        m_objects[i] = t.m_objets[i];


    return *this;
}
```

This is from an old exam. The question reads:

"
At which line is it likely that an exception might be thrown; in which state will the object `Ntuplet` be at that point (initial, coherent, incoherent, undefined)? Propose a better way to implement the class in order to avoid exception/problems."

My guess was either at `m_size = t.m_size` because I thought maybe `t.m_size` would have too large of a value, but that can't be, because then how would the `t` object even exist (the error would have appeared earlier). The only other thing that comes to mind is `++i` that might be out of range as an index..?

Thanks in advance

Edit: "Coherent" state meaning the object is in a state that doesn't have contradictory attributes, but it's not in the state we want it to be.

"Incoherent" means the attributes are not what they should be. For example, if you do `a++ = b` but the `=` operator throws an error, `a` is in an incoherent state because it was incremented even though the rest of the code didn't get to be executed. In this state, the destructor is available.

"Undefined" is the same as the above, but with the destructor unavailable as well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, I translated this exam from french myself. I updated the post, I hope it's somewhat more clear:

Answer (score 0):

The only code here that can throw is the `new` (a `std::bad_alloc` or something thrown from `T`'s constructor), or the value assignments.

If the `new` throws, then your `op=` doesn't complete, and your `m_size` will be left not matching up with the `m_objects` (which will be a dangling pointer to dead memory that used to hold an array of possibly some other size).

If one of the assignments throws, then your `op=` doesn't complete, and your `m_size` will be correct but some (or all) of the array elements will be default-constructed rather than having the value you want.

The way to fix this is to use a vector so that you don't have to worry about it. And I don't mean implementing `Ntuplet` using a vector... I mean literally replace `Ntuplet` with `std::vector`.

Comment: The constructor and assignment of type `T` could also throw.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions can only be thrown by very specific constructs. Anything that is undefined behavior, like dereferencing an invalid pointer, out-of-range access to a C-style array, undefined behavior in type conversions, is not an exception.

The only things in `Ntuplet<T>::operator=(const Ntuplet<T>& t)` that can throw an exception is the `new[]` expression (if no memory can be allocated `std::bad_alloc` or if the default constructor for `T` throws any exception) and the copy assignment of type `T` used inside the loop (depending on what type `T` is).

If the `new` throws an exception, then `m_objects` will dangling pointer because it was `delete[]`ed beforehand.
`m_size` will already have the size of the copied instance. Therefore the object will not be in any sane state.
Assuming the destructor of `Ntuplet` actually `delete[]`s the memory allocated for `m_objects`, then calling it later will cause undefined behavior because of a double-free.
If you are not going to replace `Ntuplet` or the `m_objects` member with a standard library implementation which takes care of exception-safety, then one solution for this particular exception would be to save the return value of the `new` expression to a temporary pointer `T* p` before modifying any member. Then the temporary can be assigned to `m_objects` later after the old `m_objects` was deleted.

In case the assignment operator in the loop throws an exception, the instance will also be in some partially assigned state. Calling the destructor afterwards should however be fine (assuming it only deletes `m_objects`) since `m_objects` is pointing to a `new`-allocated array. Making this exception-safe requires keeping all the old values in `m_objects`, so the loop should be moved directly after the `new[]` and it should assign to `p[]` instead of `m_objects[]`.

This does however still cause a memory leak, because the `new[]` allocated memory will not be freed if the assignment loop throws. Therefore any exception must be intercepted to delete `p`:

```
template<typename T>
    Ntuplet<T>& Ntuplet<T>::operator=(const Ntuplet<T>& t)
{
    if (&t == this)
        return *this;

    T* p = new T[t.m_size];
    try {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < t.m_size; ++i)
            p[i] = t.m_objects[i];
    } catch (...) {
        delete[] p;
        throw;
    }
    delete [] m_objects;
    m_objects = p;
    m_size = t.m_size;

    return *this;
}
```

I am assuming that the destructor of `T` does not throw any exceptions. In principle they are allowed to do that but it is unusual.